# Writing unit tests for tapir endpoints (API Layer) in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka-http, web-api-testing, tapir

I have created tapir endpoints in scala, where the architecture of the project is such that API layer calls service layer and service layer calls repo layer.

I have written unit tests for service and repo layer (using mockito), but now I could not find a good library which can be used in scala to test api layer by mocking methods of service layer.
Basically by writing unit tests for endpoints I want to test validations in api layer.

P.S. I tried using RestAssured library but it seems to be helpful for writing integration test, but not for unit test.

Edited:

The underlying server framework used is Akka HTTP

Comment: Opinion: don't test the API layer by mocking the service layer, you're isolating too much and nothing will guarantee that together they work as expected. Mocking should be only for stuff externzl to your code (database) or very specific piece of logic with a lot of complex cases.

Comment: Rather than testing the tapir library endpoint, better to validate your core functions that you use for routes.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Tapir itself does not expose endpoints, it's your http server framework that does it (http4s, zio, play...).

That means that for testing your endpoints, you should rely on what your http server framework offers: Tapir is an implementation detail, forget about it for these tests.

Comment: Underlying server framework in my case is Akka HTTP

Comment: Then look at this for instance: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html

Comment: This helped for me.